# Vuetify v-autocomplete custom filtering bug

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

```js
customFilter (item, queryText) {
      const textOne = item.designation.toLowerCase()
      const textTwo = item.reference.toLowerCase()
      const searchText = queryText.toLowerCase()
      return textOne.indexOf(searchText) > -1 ||
        textTwo.indexOf(searchText) > -1 
}
```

```html
<v-autocomplete
      dense=""
      v-model="selectedProduct"
      prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
      rounded=""
      :items="products_references_desginations"
      :filter="customFilter"
      item-text="designation"
      filled
      label="Recherche"
      single-line=""
      return-object=""
      clearable=""
    >
```

This works most of the time but it happens that I get this error :

[image]

I guess that it is the item variable in my custom filter that gets null sometimes but I have no idea why this happens. When it happens I have to reload the server and then it works fine and after some time, same error occurs.

FULL COMPONENT:

```js
import {mapGetters, mapMutations} from 'vuex'
export default {
  data: () => ({
    selectedProduct: null, 
  }),
  watch: {
    selectedProduct(prod) {
      console.log(prod)
      if(prod != null) {
        this.$emit('selectedProductFromSearchBar', prod)
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations([]),
    toProductDetailsPage(product){
      console.log(product)
    },
    customFilter (item, queryText) {
      const textOne = item.designation.toLowerCase()
      const textTwo = item.reference.toLowerCase()
      const searchText = queryText.toLowerCase()
      return textOne.indexOf(searchText) > -1 ||
        textTwo.indexOf(searchText) > -1 
    },
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['products_references_desginations']),
  },

  mounted () {
  },
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="">
    <v-autocomplete
      dense=""
      v-model="selectedProduct"
      prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
      class="pa-0 search-bar"
      rounded=""
      :items="products_references_desginations"
      :filter="customFilter"
      item-text="designation"
      filled
      color="blue-grey lighten-2"
      label="Recherche"
      single-line=""
      return-object=""
      clearable=""
    >
      <template v-slot:item="data"> 
        <template>
          <v-list-item-content style=" overflow: hidden">
            <v-list-item-title v-html="data.item.designation"></v-list-item-title>
            <v-list-item-subtitle v-html="data.item.reference"></v-list-item-subtitle>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </template>
      </template>
    </v-autocomplete>
  </div> 
</template>
```

Structure of my data :

[image]

Comment: Could we see your data structure and you full component (I mean, the full JS part of your component) ?

Comment: @EstebanMANSART I added it to the post

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my data, a null product was created I don't know how yet. But the problem is not from v-autocomplete as I thought.